# Is there anyway to add an ng-click to md-backdrop?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design

I have an angular app that needs to switch states when a sidenav is opened or closed. This works fine when opening the sidenav and closing it via a close button. However I need to attach an ng-click to the md-backdrop in the event that the user closes the sidenav by clicking outside the sidenav. Has anyone else had this issue or does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about when they press the escape button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a custom backdrop. You have the code in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j90to0mh/).

html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div layout="row" ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-backdrop class="md-sidenav-backdrop md-opaque md-default-theme md-sidenav-backdrop-custom disabled" ng-click="checkClosingForm()"></md-backdrop>
    <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" class="md-sidenav-left">
        Left Nav!
    </md-sidenav>
     <md-content>
        <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()">
          Open Side Nav
        </md-button>
      </md-content>
</div>
```

js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMaterial']);

    app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
      $scope.keepOpen = false;

      $scope.toggleLeft = toggleLeft;

      function toggleLeft(){
        $mdSidenav('left').toggle().then(function () {
                $scope.keepOpen = !$scope.keepOpen;
                if ($scope.keepOpen)
                    angular.element('md-backdrop.md-sidenav-backdrop-custom').removeClass('disabled');
                else
                   angular.element('md-backdrop.md-sidenav-backdrop-custo   
m').addClass('disabled');
        });   
  };

  $scope.checkClosingForm = function(){
      if(true){
          alert('checking...');
          toggleLeft();
      }
  };

});
```

css:

```
md-backdrop.md-sidenav-backdrop-custom{
      background-color: transparent !important;
}
md-backdrop.disabled
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This works but when I close the custom md-backdrop, I am still left with the original md-backdrop.

Comment: The original backdrop will be not displayed because $mdSidenav.toggleLeft() remove it from the DOM internally. Only remain our custom backdrop with display:none. Look the fiddle another time: https://jsfiddle.net/j90to0mh/

Comment: Remember: the best way is get out DOM modification from the controller. Always within a directive ;)

Answer (score 7):

Sidenav allows you to bind a "md-is-open" parameter that is either true or false depending on wether sidenav is open or closed. Sidenav will update it if you close sidenav by clicking on backdrop. You can bind this variable and $watch it to know sidenav state, like so:

html:

```
<div layout="row" ng-controller="MyController">
    <md-sidenav md-component-id="left" md-is-open="isSidenavOpen" class="md-sidenav-left">
        Left Nav!
    </md-sidenav>
</div>
```

js:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
    $scope.isSidenavOpen = false;

    $scope.$watch('isSidenavOpen', function(isSidenavOpen) {
       alert('sidenav is ' + (isSidenavOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'));
    });
});
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qo1gmrrr/

Comment: This solution looks slick, but doesn't works. Any update on this one?

Comment: @dr.dimitru It does work. I am using angularjs 1.5.3; angular material 1.1.0-rc2

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can handle sidenav open/close through md-is-open, but you can not prevent closing it

Answer (score 0):

If need event for mb-bottom-sheet use onRemove:

```
$mdBottomSheet
    .show({
        templateUrl: '_TEMPLATE_FILE_',
        onRemove: function (scope, element, options) {
            var scrollmask = document.getElementsByClassName('md-scroll-mask');
            var backdrop = document.getElementsByTagName('md-backdrop');
            angular.element(scrollmask).remove();
            angular.element(backdrop).remove();
            angular.element(element).remove();
            $mdUtil.enableScrolling();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution without using $scope or $watch, or manipulating DOM:

in my view:

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-4dp" 
            md-swipe-left="drawerCtrl.toggle()"  md-component-id="left">
......
</md-sidenav>
<md-backdrop class="md-sidenav-backdrop" ng-click="drawerCtrl.toggle()" 
             ng-show="drawerCtrl.drawerOpen"></md-backdrop>
```

in DrawerController:

```
 this.toggle = function () {    
                $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
                self.drawerOpen = $mdSidenav('left').isOpen();
                ....
    };
```

And of course, on your button which opens/closes the sidebar:

```
<md-button ng-click="drawerController.toggle()"></md-button>
```